# Is "Do a little, often" good English?

Tags: grammaticality

I just can't tell if this is a proper sentence and whether it can stand on its own like that.

I am trying to say do a small amount of work (on something), but often.

Comment: If it's understandable, it's good enough.

Comment: Actually, it would need a bit more than that, like something that a native speaker would actually say.

Comment: 'Little and often' is a common phrase. If you are advising someone who is learning a skill, you could say 'Practise little and often'.